In WordPress, creating user as administrator
In a WordPress instalation, using MySQL command I created a new user and then I gave it administrator capabilities. I did something like this:
INSERT INTO wp_users (user_login, user_pass, user_nicename, user_email, user_registered, user_status) VALUES ('matias', MD5('my_password'), 'Admin Matias', 'admin@myorg.com', NOW(), 0);

INSERT INTO wp_usermeta (user_id, meta_key, meta_value) VALUES (LAST_INSERT_ID(), 'capabilities', 'a:1:{s:13:"administrator";b:1;}');

It worked but when I signed in, I did not have access to dashboard.
Then I signed out and logged in with original Admin user, I accessed the dashboard, I oppened "users" and saw the newly created user but the role was missing.
I then gave it admin role and now in the DB (wp_usermeta) I have a duplicate value like so:
82  4   capabilities    a:1:{s:13:"administrator";b:1;}
84  5   capabilities    a:1:{s:13:"administrator";b:1;}
What did I do wrong in MySQL command?
Why didn't it worked at first?

"I have a duplicate value like so" - first one would be the wp_user_meta record ID (umeta_id), and the second one the user id, I presume? So apparently you inserted a capability for user ID 4, whereas the actual user ID appears to be 5?

Well the SQL command was supposed to select the latest inserted ID:
INSERT INTO wp_usermeta (user_id, meta_key, meta_value) VALUES (LAST_INSERT_ID(), 'capabilities', 'a:1:{s:13:"administrator";b:1;}');

Did you use phpmyadmin to execute the sql statements?

A quick minor note:  I would try to change capabilities to wp_capabilities, which is the common key used on WordPress for storing user roles.

@Shadow, I didn't use phpMyAdmin. I used AdminerEvo to execute SQL statements, because I'm using Local by Flywheel.

Thank you @Domiserver, perhaps you're right. I'll try it later today.

@FroPT Yes Domiserver  is totally right, you have to use wp_capabilities meta key.

The issue with your MySQL command is that while you correctly added the capabilities in wp_usermeta, you missed adding the wp_user_level key, which is necessary for WordPress to fully recognize the user's role and grant dashboard access. To properly create an administrator user via MySQL, you should first insert the user into wp_users, retrieve the user ID, then insert both the wp_capabilities and wp_user_level meta keys into wp_usermeta, setting wp_capabilities to 'a:1:{s:13:"administrator";b:1;}' and wp_user_level to 10. To fix the duplicate capabilities, you can remove one of the entries from wp_usermeta.
